# Find Shelveset of Another User

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, team-explorer, shelveset

When I follow instructions to [find a shelveset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244648/can-anybody-find-the-tfs-unshelve-option-in-visual-studio-2012), I'm given a list of all my personal shelvesets.  But what I want is to view and unshelve from another user's selection.  Other developers can simply change the user to whoever they want.  No such option exists for me.

I've told my TFS admin about this issue.  The response I got was that "We haven’t locked anything down, you should be able to view others' shelvesets."  Nevertheless, I can't see others' shelvesets.

What could be causing this?  What specific issue or permission(s) should the TFS admin check to confirm "we havn't locked anything down?"

Comment: What error do you receive?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should be able to simply type in a different user name in the Find Shelvesets window and hit Enter (if that's not working whats the error message):

[image]

Comment: Look and feel: it doesn't look like a field that can be edited.  What do you know?

Comment: Had to be an exact match for me to get a hit

Comment: Yes, I found words from the title or words from the user's Display Name as displayed in TFS do **not** work.  Only thing I found that worked was the user's underlying AD username, which TFS doesn't display in most places :/

Comment: Tried this but it didn't work for me. I could see myself but not other coworkers. Using the option below worked for me.

Answer (score 56):

I also had this issue, and typing in other names didn't yield any results.

Instead I found that if I search for **`*`** then I can see all shelfsets and their name, and I can hover over the name to see the owner.

[image: Using star to view all shelfsets]

Comment: This helped me find it, I'm an intern working on a 6-man team (plus the two for the interns so technically 8). And we can't find each others changes in TFS but searching with `*` reveals all changes and revealed our sets. I'm convinced visual studio hates me :-(

Comment: Even putting * did not work for me. I am not at all able to view Shelvesets created by other users. Is there any settings which I need to check or it is some right related issue?

Answer (score 2):

There is a UserVoice idea for [improvements to the Visual Studio Find Shelvesets Search box UI](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9069982-improvement-for-find-shelveset-section). Suggest you up vote that idea and add a comment regarding your specific issue. That might get some action from Microsoft.

In my current project environment (VS2015/TFS2013) you have to provide an exact user/AD account name. If you try a partial name you get an error msg

> Could not retrieve shelvesets: TF14045: The identity calvert is not a recognized identity.

A wildcard character * works but generates too many results and you can't filter them.

The wildcard does not work when ot combined with a fragment; "calvert*" gives an error msg

> Could not retrieve shelvesets: TF10131: The shelveset name calvert* contains more than 64 characters, contains one of the following characters: "/:<>\|*?; or ends with a space. Type a valid name and try again.

All in all a poor experience.