# TFS 2017 - Find Shelveset in VS2015 only searches for username

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, tfvc

We recently upgraded to TFS 2017 update 2.

Users are now required to search for the username instead of the display name in the "Find Shelvesets" menu through Visual Studio 2015.

Is this intended behavior ? in the past we were able to search on display name.

So "Firstname Lastname" does not find anything
but "firstname.lastname" does find the shelvesets.

This goes for all users.

**Update**: Issue confirmed by Microsoft, user voice created
https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32204305-search-shelvesets-in-tfs2017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE3:**

As Nico comment below:

> "Someone else from Microsoft confirmed by issue and raised a [User
>   voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32204305-search-shelvesets-in-tfs2017)

---

No, in Visual Studio 2015 we can only search the Shelvesets by the **owner** (That is the Display Name, **user's underlying AD username**).

However you can use "`*`" to list all shelvesets, then hover over the shelveset name to see the owner, then search by owner.

There are some user voices here to suggest improvements for searching Shelvesets in Visual Studio, you can go and vote them up to achieve that in future:

- [Improvement for Find Shelveset section.](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/9069982-improvement-for-find-shelveset-section)
- [Shelveset search improvement](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037731-shelveset-search-improvement)

Reference the similar thread: [Find Shelveset of Another User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622459/find-shelveset-of-another-user)

---

**UPDATE:**

Make sure you are searching use the real `display name` but not the `user name` or first/last name. Just as I mentioned in above answer, try enter `*` to list all the shelvesets, then put your mouse on the specific shelveset to check the `owner` (display name), then search with the display name. Note that it's owner, the full name displayed there, part of the name is not worked. Reference below screenshot.

---

**UPDATE2:**

Search by AD UserName is not supported for now. So, I suggest you to vote up the existhing user voices (mentioned above) or submit a new user voice to suggest the feature.

[image]

Comment: Is this something that changed with TFS2017 ? We are pretty sure the search by display name worked in TFS 2015.

Comment: @Nico Nothing changed about this feature. Search by display name worked in VS 2015 for both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017 as I mentioned in above answer, the display name is just  the owner.

Comment: Ok, but in our case searching for the display name no longer works..
What could be the reason of that.

Comment: @Nico Make sure you are searching use the real `display name` but not the `user name` or first/last name. Just as I mentioned in above answer, try enter `*` to list all the shelvesets, then put your mouse on the specific shelveset to check the `owner` (display name), then search with the display name. Note that it's owner, the full name displayed there, part of the name is not worked. See the screenshot in the updated answer.

Comment: I did, did a search for another Shelveset, when i hover over i see the display name we expect "Lastname, Firstname" in this case.

When entering this same "Lastname, Firstname" in the search, it comes back with "No shelvesets found for "Lastname, Firstname"

Comment: @Nico Yes, it's the expected behavior, as I mentioned above it **only** support search by display name (owner). Also refer to JohnC's answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622459/find-shelveset-of-another-user). It's not supporeted search by "`Lastname, Firstname`" There are user voices to suggest the feature but not acheved yet for now, so you can go and vote up the user voices or submit a new [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services) to suggest the feature.

Comment: I hear what you are saying but it doesnt make sense to me.
Earlier you mentioned you should be able to search for the string that is shown when you hover over the user when search for all Shelvesets.
In our case, the Owner string is: LastName, FirstName.
Search for that in TFS 2015 worked for use, since the upgrade to 2017 it doesnt. You mentioned no changes have been made, but we still see a change in behavior. Could this be an issue ?

Comment: @Nico I suggest you test this in another clean client. I tested at my side, both TFS 2015 and TFS 2017 have the same behavior. You can only search by owner (the whole string displayed when hover mouse on the specific shelveset, If it displayed like you said `LastName, FirstName`, then you sould search by `LastName, FirstName`.) If you still have different behavior with the clean client, then please share the details for further troubleshooting (screenshots is better if possbile )

Comment: tried some more scenarios. All of our users have a Lastname, Firstname format. So with a comma in it. Our build service account does not. So i searched by its username TFSBUILD and got the results, the name "TFS Build" was listed as the owner, a search for "TFS Build" shows the same amount of shelvesets. Searching for my own "Lastname, Firstname" also works.. but those are the only owner names that can be searched by, all other users need to be looked up through this AD UserName. If you have an email address i can send you some screenshots

Comment: @Nico Yes, I know what you said, that's the expected behavior and the only acceptted way to search for normal users (owner names), it's as designed. Search by AD UserName is not supported for now. So, I suggest you to vote up the existhing user voices or submit a new user voice to suggest the feature.

Comment: i dont think you understand what i write.
At this moment searching by AD Username is the only thing that does work... searching by the owner string does not work, the owner string is the "lastname, firstname". Only searching for your own name works..

Comment: @Nico OK, you can clarify your question with the screenshots posted ,or put the screenshots on OneDrive then share the link here. I will check that again.

Comment: Can i send a personal message or email to you ? i dont like to put employee names here.

Comment: @Nico Sorry, we cannot do that based on the company policies, you can drop the sensitive information as I posted the screenshot above, then add notes accordingly in the screenshots.

Comment: Someone else from Microsoft confirmed by issue and raised a User voice https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/32204305-search-shelvesets-in-tfs2017