# Unshelving changes in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, unshelve

In Visual Studio 2008, I can unshelve changes from the solution explorer context menu. It was easy back then.

Now I am using VS2015. I found that you'll be able to do this in the later versions by selecting Team Explorer >  Pending changes > Actions > Find Shelvesets.

They must have a good reason for doing this. Does anyone know why they made it so?

Can you share your workaround for this?

Comment: They possibly did that because the functionality is a source control functionality. Why they buried it, not sure. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18405277/4228458) to see if you can add it back.

Comment: I think this is more of a gripe than a question. However, I happen to share the gripe, so I'm upvoting it.